# Copy data From Listbox1 to Listbox2

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox, selecteditem

in c# I have a listbox1 like this:

```
lstCorsoAll.DisplayMember = "description";
lstCorsoAll.ValueMember = "id";
lstCorsoAll.DataSource = dtData;
```

where dtData is a DataTable form a SQL query.

I want to copy selected items from listbox1 to a listbox2 with a button.

If I use this code:

```
foreach (object item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(item);
}
```

in listbox2 I get always System.data.datarowview because listbox1.SelectedItems is a DataRowView

So I used:

```
listbox2.DataSource = listbox1.SelectedItems;
listbox2.DisplayMember = listbox1.DisplayMember;
listbox2.ValueMember = listbox1.ValueMember;
```

and it works fine (I get the correct displayed value), but if a repeat the operation (I select a new value from listbox1) and press the button, items in listbox2 are always the same, listbox2 does not update.

After this, I want to save items in listbox2 to DB, using listbox2 items valueMember as key on MySQL Table

Can you help me pls?!
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The listbox didn't detect that you have changed the DataSource. It will only refresh when Datasource has changed, so set DataSource to null first:

```
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = data;
```

You could also clear the items then set the DataSource again:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
listBox1.DataSource = data;
```